# Behaviour of rotating image between Kivy and Python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having problem understanding what Kivy is doing behind the scenes when using the Kivy language when rotating images and moving them.

Below is a code that's is supposed to draw two images in a 45 degree angle on the screen and then for every mouse click rotate it more and then move it to the right on the screen.

The first image is drawn by using the rotate defined in the Kivy language where the second is where I try to redo it in only python (to understand better what Kivy is actually doing), but I'm failing since the Python version firstly does not move the image to the right when I increase x, but it looks like the whole coordinate system has been rotated for that image since it moves in 45 degree angle up the screen, and secondly it does not rotate that image when I click.

What am I missing, and what would be needed to do it in Python (without using the Kivy language) to acquire the same behaviour as the first image is using?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.graphics import Rotate
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.graphics.context_instructions import PopMatrix, PushMatrix


Builder.load_string('''
<TestKV>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix
        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            axis: (0, 0, 1)
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
''')

class TestKV(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super(TestKV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x
        self.angle = 45

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.angle += 20
        self.x += 10


class TestPY(Image):
    angle = NumericProperty(0)

    def __init__(self, x, **kwargs):
        super(TestPY, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.x = x
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            rot = Rotate()
            rot.angle = 45
            rot.origin = self.center
            rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.angle += 20
        self.x += 10

class MainWidget(Widget):
    #this is the main widget that contains the game.

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.all_sprites = []

        self.k = TestKV(source="myTestImage.bmp", x=10)
        self.add_widget(self.k)

        self.p = TestPY(source="myTestImage.bmp", x=200)
        self.add_widget(self.p)


class TheApp(App):

    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        app = MainWidget()
        parent.add_widget(app)

        return parent

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never change the angle of the `Rotate` instruction. You have an `angle` property on your widget, but that isn't linked to anything. Try updating the `Rotate` instruction instead:

```
class TestPY(Image):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestPY, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # self.x = x -- not necessary, x is a property and will be handled by super()
        with self.canvas.before:
            PushMatrix()
            self.rot = Rotate()
            self.rot.angle = 45
            self.rot.origin = self.center
            self.rot.axis = (0, 0, 1)
        with self.canvas.after:
            PopMatrix()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.x += 10
        self.rot.origin = self.center  # center has changed; update here or bind instead
        self.rot.angle += 20
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer: this is the only answer on SO that doesn't assume a simplistic static rotation in a `.kv` file.